# Remote Support (Remote Desktop) Possible From Overseas?

Tags: desktop, remote-access, latency, remote-connection

bit of an unusual question here -

I am a desktop support professional located in the US, whose clients are all in the US or Canada. Essentially my job entails taking remote control of PCs and performing repairs through Logmein Rescue.

I'm considering making a move to mainland Asia and was wondering if it would be realistically possible to do my job from that location, latency wise.

Essentially what I'm worried about is the lag being so high my pace will slow to a crawl or my sessions will drop out.

Considering I'm using a fast (20mb+) connection with low latency, do you think it will be possible to effectively remote control a US PC from Asia?

Comment: It would depend on where in asia, and the connection. And whether the cables were eaten by sharks. We've been having high latency between us and our HQ in london cause the fibre optic cable between us was severed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'it really depends'.

'Asia' is a *huge* place, and quality of internet access is highly dependant on where you are, who your ISP is and how you're routed.

There's a few things I'd consider.

There's a cottage industry of [scammers in india who do this as a business](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/10/i-am-calling-you-from-windows-a-tech-support-scammer-dials-ars-technica/) so clearly its doable.

If you're in china, stuff occationally gets [blocked by the GFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Shield_Project) - though I've never heard of it happening with logmein.

At the end of the day? *Talk to locals*. Maybe get someone who lives in your new city to let you know what its like. Maybe tip him for connecting to your system, and working on it to see what its like from the customer side.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, that's some good food for thought. The country specifically I was thinking of was Thailand, which has good (but not superb) internet. All things considered it's not that far from India so clearly its doable on some level.